# Help identifying the pest/disease on my Schismatoglottis

Tags: houseplants, diseases, pests, fungus

I've attached a pic of the leaf of a Schismatoglottis I got recently.  It's otherwise happy, healthy and flourishing but a few weeks after new leaves emerge they are covered in a slightly brownish powdery/grainy residue and I've noticed what looks like a fine web on the leaf.  There are no visible insects/spiders/creepy crawlies, so I'm not sure that the webbing is spider related.  Hopefully the pic is good enough to see what I mean, if not I'm happy to attempt a better shot...

I appreciate that a Schismatoglottis isn't the most commonly grown of houseplants, but any info on similar symptoms on similar plants would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: leaf showing webbing]

Comment: PS, It died.  And gave spider mites to a bunch of my other plants.  Although the answer was very accurate I wish I had just binned the thing as soon as they first turned up.  I would highly recommend anyone else do the same, controlling these things is hard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tiny objects in the webbing showing in the photo, some of which look white; these might be spider mites (they're not always red) and if you have a strong magnifying glass, you may be able to see them moving to confirm. Methods to control them are mentioned here https://aces.nmsu.edu/ces/yard/2008/010508.html, but take note of the warning regarding using insecticidal soaps, which might damage some sensitive plants. I don't know enough about this particular plant to say whether its sensitive to soaps or not and it looks like Google doesn't know either, so try gently showering them off, and if you need to try soap  treatments, perhaps just use it on a test area first to see if it's damaging.